# Who can be a member in "Membership was restricted to people over 30"?

Tags: sentence-meaning, phrase-meaning, comparative-constructions

What does the following sentence mean?

> Membership was restricted to people over 30.

1. Only people over 30 can be member.
2. Only people under 30 can be member.
3. It can be both.

Comment: The statement is ambiguous, but likely 1.

Comment: Yes,  it means people over 30 could be members, not can be member.

Comment: I don't think the question is about the time.

Answer (score 2):

As is clearly stated "over 30" means "more than 30". "Restricted" means "limited", "restricted to" means "to limit something to a particular category of people". So the first meaning is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the opposites:

*restricted* X *open* **and** *over* X *under*

> Membership was **open**(only) to people **under** 30.

From that, it can be understood that people above 30 are not allowed to tak eup the membership. Whereas, people only people under 30 can.

> Membership was **restricted** to people **over** 30.